# jQuery calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```
        (function( $ ){
        var monthNames = [ "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
          "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь" ];

        var dayNames = ["Пн","Вт","Ср","Чт","Пт","Сб","Вс"];
        var now = new Date();

        var methods = {
             init : function( options ) {
                var settings = $.extend( {
                    'year'          : now.getFullYear(),
                    'month'         : now.getMonth(),
                    'link'          : '%y/%m/%d',
                    'url'           : '',
                    'dates'         : []
                }, options);

                return this.each(function(){
                    if (!$(this).data('year')){
                        $(this).data('year',settings.year);
                    }
                    if (!$(this).data('month')){
                        $(this).data('month',settings.month);
                    }
                    if (!$(this).data('link')){
                        $(this).data('link',settings.link);
                    }
                    $(this).data('dates',settings.dates);
                    $(this).data('url',settings.url);
                    methods.render($(this));
                });

             },
             destroy : function( ) {

               return this.each(function(){
                 $(this).html('');
               })

             },
            render : function( elem ) { 
                    year = elem.data('year');
                    month = elem.data('month');
                    link = elem.data('link');
                    dates = elem.data('dates');
                    date = new Date(year,month,1);

                    elem.html('<table class="calendar"></table>');
                    var calendar=elem.find('.calendar');
                    calendar.append('<tr class="calendar-header"><th colspan="7"><a href="#" class="icon-chevron-left calendar-prev-month"></a>'+monthNames[month]+' '+year+'<a href="#" class="icon-chevron-right calendar-next-month"></a></th></tr>');
                    calendar.append('<tr class="calendar-week"><th>'+dayNames.join('</th><th>')+'</th></tr>');
                    var str = '<tr>';
                    var week = date.getDay();
                    if (week == 0) { week=7}
                    for (day=1;day<week;day++){
                        str=str+"<td></td>";
                    }
                    date.setMonth(month+1);
                    date.setDate(0);
                    for (day=1;day<=date.getDate();day++){
                        var link_href = link.replace("%y",year).replace("%m",month+1).replace("%d",day);
                        var day_text = '';
                        if ($.inArray(day, dates)>=0){
                            day_text = '<a href="'+link_href+'" class="calendar-day-link">'+day+'</a>';
                        } else {
                            day_text = day;
                        }
                        str=str+'<td>'+day_text+'</td>';
                        if (week++ % 7 == 0){
                            str=str+"</tr></tr>";       
                        }
                    }
                    str = str + '</tr>';
                    calendar.append(str);
                    calendar.find('.calendar-next-month').click(methods.next_month);
                    calendar.find('.calendar-prev-month').click(methods.prev_month);
             },
             next_month : function( e ) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                elem = $(this).parents('.calendar').parent();
                year = elem.data('year');
                month = elem.data('month')+1;
                url = elem.data('url');
                if (month>11){
                    year++;
                    month=0;
                }
                elem.data('year',year).data('month',month);
                $.getJSON(url+'?year='+year+'&month='+(month+1),function(data) {
                    elem.data('dates',data);
                    methods.render(elem);
                });
             },
             prev_month : function( e ) {
               e.preventDefault();
               elem = $(this).parents('.calendar').parent();
                year = elem.data('year');
                month = elem.data('month')-1;
                url = elem.data('url');
                if (month==-1){
                    year--;
                    month=11;
                }
                elem.data('year',year).data('month',month);
                $.getJSON(url+'?year='+year+'&month='+(month+1),function(data) {
                    elem.data('dates',data);
                    methods.render(elem);
                });
             },
          };

      $.fn.calendar = function( method ) {  

        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided

        if ( methods[method] ) {
          return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
          return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
          $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }    
      };
    })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- THANK YOU for having all your code and variables in English, very nice
- In init I would suggest you extract `data`, fill it in if needed and put it back, so going from this

  ```
          return this.each(function(){
              if (!$(this).data('year')){
                  $(this).data('year',settings.year);
              }
              if (!$(this).data('month')){
                  $(this).data('month',settings.month);
              }
              if (!$(this).data('link')){
                  $(this).data('link',settings.link);
              }
              $(this).data('dates',settings.dates);
              $(this).data('url',settings.url);
              methods.render($(this));
          });
  ```

  to this:

  ```
          return this.each(function(){
              var data = $(this).data() || {};
              data.year = data.year || settings.year;
              data.month = data.month || settings.month;
              data.link = data.link || settings.link;
              data.dates = settings.dates;
              data.url = settings.url;
              $(this).data(data);
              methods.render($(this));
          });
  ```

  It looks DRY'er and the reduced amount of calls to `$(this).data()` should make it more efficient as well.
- You could do the same with `year` and `month` in `next_month` and `prev_month`.
- lowerCamelCasing is how JavaScript ought to be done: `next_month` -> `nextMonth`, 
  `prev_month` -> `previousMonth` etc.
- You should really look into a templating routine/library for building your HTML, extracting your HTML templates into `var`s and making it more readable by splitting over multiple lines. You could even use templating to construct the JSON URL's.
- From JsHint ( jshint.com )

  - `year` , `month`, `link`, `dates` etc. are declared in your code without `var`, polluting the global namespace
  - If you want to compare with `0`, you should use `===` not `==`